# add comments underneath an iFrame tab

Tags: facebook, iframe

I've created an iFrame app and added it to a fan page like here.
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brad-Holland/224781117540627?sk=app_123543567752303

I would like to add comments box underneath the iframe so that its part of facebook and not my iframe.
Is this possible?
thanks in advance.
Brad

UPDATE

Hey many thanks for your response. Although this doesn't help me.
I am (as you can see from the link I showed you) able to put comments in the iFrame application see here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brad-Holland/224781117540627?sk=app_123543567752303

however, because the comments are part of the iFrame then It starts giving me those awful scroll bars as soon as more than 2 comments are made. I want the comments to be outside of the iFrame. or at least stop the scroll bars from appearing..

any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Warm Regards,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) you can use code somthing like specific to your post and this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198/) may also help you.

and you can also have comment option with the new like button for the app for that see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)